Magento 2 : Validate Shipping Methods According to Custom Checkbox Select
I have created a checkbox in shipping form for local pick-up option. If user checks it, shipping address get populated as the store address.

Now I want to show, the custom created, shipping method for Local Pick-up only if the user checks the checkbox. Otherwise Local pick-up should not show.

Please tell me the best approach to do so in my custom module.
Thanks in advance!

it will be better to show a screenshot of what you want to achieve.
